# Why the system enter two times in an hook_node_presave?

Tags: 7, hooks

I've write a simple module for my sites, where I populate a node reference by code.

I use [hook_node_presave](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7), but I notice that drupal enters TWO times in this hook, so if my node reference field is multiple, it populates it two times.

Is there something wrong on my code or is normal?
In the presave hook I've to load another node and then save it

I have something like this:

```
   function alterator_node_presave($node) {
      if ($node->type == 'partner_progetto') {
        // here I load a node "progetto" 
        // that is referenced on my partner_progetto node
        $progetto = node_load($node->field_progetto_rif['und'][0]['nid']);

        // here I load another node "soggetto" 
        // that is referenced on my partner_progetto node
        $soggetto = node_load($node->field_soggetto['und'][0]['nid']);

        // then I've to fill a node_reference in the node $progetto, 
        // using the nid of $soggetto
        $progetto->field_soggetto_ref['und'][]['nid'] = $soggetto->nid;

        node_save($progetto);   
      } 
   }
```

In this hook the system enter 2 times, so when I save a "partner progetto" node that has a reference to the node soggetto with nid '150' I've that the "progetto" node has this structure:

```
$progetto->field_soggetto_ref
  ['und']
    [0]['nid'] = 150,
    [1]['nid'] = 150;
```

The value of this field is filled two times.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `node_save($progetto);` from `alterator_node_presave` and try. Because `hook_node_presave` is called just before the `node_save`. It can be reason of saving the field twice.

Answer (score 1):

`hook_node_presave()` is invoked once for each node. As you implementation calls [node_save()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/node_save/7), which then invokes `hook_node_presave()` again, your hook is invoked twice, once for each node.

Possibly, you could have an infinite loop, if `$node->field_progetto_rif['und'][0]['nid']` is the node ID of a node whose content type is "partner_progetto"; be sure to avoid that.

Your code is the adding a new node reference all the times a node is saved, as you use `$progetto->field_soggetto_ref['und'][]['nid']`, and not `$progetto->field_soggetto_ref['und'][0]['nid']`.

Comment: But in my hook there is an if based on node type. If it enter in the hook when is saving $progetto, the system should simply go away because it doesn't enter in the if. Or not?

Comment: `hook_node_presave()` is called for every node, independently from its content type. It is invoked, but with your actual code it doesn't do anything; still, the hook is invoked twice.

Comment: I know it, but the question is: why it enter two times in the if?

Comment: Actually, you are adding a new node reference every time the node is saved.

Comment: Yes, but only when the $node->type is "partner_progetto". Why enter in the "if" if the $node->type isn't "partner_progetto"?